# Navigation Sending Simple Goal from Class

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm having trouble converting the [Navigation Tutorial "SendingSimpeGoals"](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals) to a format where the functionality can be used out of a library. When splitting everything up into a h- and cpp-file I get the below errors when running "catkin_make".
If I replace the source code in *node.cpp* with the tutorial code, everything compiles and runs fine.

I built the minimum example below to show the error. I would appreciate any help, thank you in advance!
I am running ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04 on a VMware Workstation.

Following, the error messages and the source code:

```
/home/marco/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libincluded_class.so: undefined reference to `actionlib::ConnectionMonitor::goalConnectCallback(ros::SingleSubscriberPublisher const&)'
/home/marco/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libincluded_class.so: undefined reference to `actionlib::ConnectionMonitor::goalDisconnectCallback(ros::SingleSubscriberPublisher const&)'
/home/marco/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libincluded_class.so: undefined reference to `actionlib::GoalIDGenerator::generateID()'
/home/marco/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libincluded_class.so: undefined reference to `actionlib::ConnectionMonitor::cancelDisconnectCallback(ros::SingleSubscriberPublisher const&)'
min_example/CMakeFiles/node.dir/build.make:115: recipe for target '/home/marco/catkin_ws/devel/lib/min_example/node' failed
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2957: recipe for target 'min_example/CMakeFiles/node.dir/all' failed
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
/home/marco/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libincluded_class.so: undefined reference to `actionlib::ConnectionMonitor::ConnectionMonitor(ros::Subscriber&, ros::Subscriber&)'
/home/marco/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libincluded_class.so: undefined reference to `actionlib::ConnectionMonitor::cancelConnectCallback(ros::SingleSubscriberPublisher const&)'
/home/marco/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libincluded_class.so: undefined reference to `actionlib::ConnectionMonitor::waitForActionServerToStart(ros::Duration const&, ros::NodeHandle const&)'
/home/marco/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libincluded_class.so: undefined reference to `actionlib::ConnectionMonitor::processStatus(boost::shared_ptr<actionlib_msgs::GoalStatusArray_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/home/marco/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libincluded_class.so: undefined reference to `actionlib::GoalIDGenerator::GoalIDGenerator()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/marco/catkin_ws/devel/lib/min_example/node] Error 1
make[1]: *** [min_example/CMakeFiles/node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
16:57:59: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Project (kit: Desktop)
When executing step "Make"
```

Here is my source code:
**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(min_example)

add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    actionlib
    move_base_msgs
    roscpp
    )

catkin_package(
    )

include_directories(
    include
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ../../devel/include
    )

add_library(included_class src/included_class.cpp)
add_executable(node src/node.cpp)


target_link_libraries(
    node
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
    included_class
    )

add_dependencies(included_class ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
add_dependencies(node ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

install(DIRECTORY config launch include
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)
```

**package.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
<name>min_example</name>
<version>0.0.0</version>
<description>min_example</description>


<maintainer email="marco@todo.todo">marco</maintainer>

<license>TODO</license>


<buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
<build_depend>actionlib</build_depend>
<build_depend>move_base_msgs</build_depend>
<build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
<build_export_depend>actionlib</build_export_depend>
<build_export_depend>move_base_msgs</build_export_depend>
<build_export_depend>roscpp</build_export_depend>
<exec_depend>actionlib</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>move_base_msgs</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>

<export>

</export>
</package>
```

**node.cpp**

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "included_class.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "node");
    Included_Class included_class;
    return 0;
}
```

**included_class.h**

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "ros/console.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Point.h"
#include <move_base_msgs/MoveBaseAction.h>
#include <actionlib/client/simple_action_client.h>

class Included_Class
{
public:
    Included_Class();
    void publish_nav_goal(geometry_msgs::Point nav_goal);
private:
    typedef actionlib::SimpleActionClient<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseAction> MoveBaseClient;
    MoveBaseClient ac;
};
```

**included_class.cpp**

```
#include "included_class.h"

Included_Class::Included_Class()
    :ac("move_base", true)
{
  while(!ac.waitForServer(ros::Duration(5.0))){
    ROS_INFO("Waiting for the move_base action server to come up");
  }

}
void Included_Class::publish_nav_goal(geometry_msgs::Point nav_goal)
{
    move_base_msgs::MoveBaseGoal goal;
    
     goal.target_pose.header.frame_id = "base_link";
        goal.target_pose.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();

        goal.target_pose.pose.position = nav_goal;
        goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;

        ROS_INFO("Sending goal");
        ac.sendGoal(goal);

        ac.waitForResult();

        if(ac.getState() == actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState::SUCCEEDED)
          ROS_INFO("Hooray, the base moved 1 meter forward");
        else
          ROS_INFO("The base failed to move forward 1 meter for some reason");
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319115/navigation-sending-simple-goal-from-class/) by [MarcoStb](https://answers.ros.org/users/34552/marcostb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2019-03-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to find a solution myself. The error was caused by using a wrong order for `target_link_libraries`. So, instead of listing `${catkin_LIBRARIES}` first, `included_class` has to come first (see below code snippet).

```
...
target_link_libraries( node
    included_class
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
    )
...
```

---

Originally posted by [MarcoStb](https://answers.ros.org/users/34552/marcostb/) with karma: 80 on 2019-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarcoStb](https://answers.ros.org/users/34552/marcostb/) on 2019-03-22**:
Can someone please accept this as the answer, I don't have enough points? Thank you!